# Why is Java producing faulty output for lengths > 10000 in this algorithm?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have this assignment for university, where we are supposed to implement a sorting algorithm similar to insertion sort.
The algorithm has a data Structure consisting of 2 Stacks S and T. The elements in S are supposed to be decreasing montonic and T is supposed to be increasing monotonic, both Stacks from top to bottom.
I have already implemented this and do not need help with that. However when playing around with bigger input arrays, around the size of n=10000 I get weird outputs.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int length = 10000;
    int[] input = new int[length];
    int j = length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

        input[i] = j;
        j --;
    }
    Datastruct Test = new Datastruct();

    Test.sort(input);
    System.out.println("S = " + Test.S);
    System.out.println("T = " + Test.T);
    Test.sort_back();
    System.out.println("Sorted Array: " + Test.S);
}


static class Datastruct{
    Stack<Integer> S;
    Stack<Integer> T;
    public Datastruct(){
        this.S = new Stack<Integer>();
        this.T = new Stack<Integer>();
    }
    public void sort_back() {
        while(! T.isEmpty()){
            S.push(T.pop());
        }
    }
    public void sort(int[] input) {
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            if (S.isEmpty() && T.isEmpty()) {
                S.push(input[i]);
            }else if (!S.isEmpty() && S.peek() <= input[i]) {
                S.push(input[i]);
            } else {
                while(!S.isEmpty() && S.peek() > input[i]  ){
                    T.push(S.pop());
                }
                S.push(input[i]);
            }
            int tmp = S.pop();
            while(!S.isEmpty() && !T.isEmpty() && tmp > T.peek()){
                 S.push(T.pop());
            }
            S.push(tmp);

        }
    }

}
```

When I run this code I expect the output to be in the form:

S = (...)

T =  (...)

Sorted Array: (...)

However for big lengths I get:

T = (...)

T = (...)

Sorted Array: (...)

The code is written in Java, executed on a Macbook and run in Eclipse if that is helpful.

Why is it that the output gets messed up? Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no reason you would get `T =` instead of `S =` unless it is Eclipse which is failing to handle large buffers. Try not printing all the contents to see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have too small a buffer wherever you are trying to display the output?

The output i get in eclipse is

```
S = [1]
T = [10000, 9999, ... , 2]
Sorted Array: [1,2, ... , 10000]
```

I omitted intermediate values.

Try running it in a terminal to see if there is a difference?

Or right click console -> preferences -> tick out "limit console output" and try again.